# Media Keys for Specific, Uncommon media sites?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, autohotkey, media-keys

I like listening to an old-style radio show called Adventures in Odyssey. It's absolutely awesome, and the site is well made except for a few things. The player automatically continues to the next episode, you cannot use space or the media keys to pause/resume the episodes, although you can use the arrow keys to skip or go back episodes, and if you just paused the media you can hit space or enter to resume but not to pause again. I would like to learn how to cause the webpage to "click" the pause/play button based on if I hit the pause/play button on the keyboard. I know something about HTML and I know how to use AutoHotKey to affect the media keys, and I also know something about javascript and would not be opposed to making my own extension. I attempted to make a custom StreamKey for the already made chrome extension StreamKeys, but the instructions on GitHub to do so were very unclear and unspecific as to how to do it, so I came here.